# TraMineR Sorting Index plots

Tags: r, traminer

I need some advice on how to sort sequence indexplot by state. In other words, instead of having individual sequence stocked on each other by most frequent, I would like to see sequences which start (beginning of sequence) with a certain state at the bottom of the plot.

Is this possible?

Here is an example of my syntax:

```
seqIplot(EMSMI.seq, border = NA, group = EMSMI$ RACE, sortv = dist.mostfreq)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. You can set the sortv argument to "from.start" or "from.end".

```
seqIplot(EMSMI.seq, border = NA, group = EMSMI$ RACE, sortv = "from.start")
```

Hope this helps.